# Java EE, accent in url, request.getParameter wrong value

Tags: java, url, servlets, character-encoding, diacritics

I work in Java on a web application servlet / jsp and I have a problem today:
After validating a form, I pass the value of an input field as a parameter (`GET`).
I was careful to use the method `javax.net.URLEncoder.encode (String, "UTF-8")` but when this setting is composed of accents, the encoding of the value obtained in the second servlet is incorrect.
However I use the method `URLDecoder.decode ((String) request.getParameter ("id"), "UTF-8")`

```
Ex: 
id = éssai ==> http://127.0.0.1:8080/LdapJavaNet/groupe?action=consulter&id=%C3%A9ssai

print (URLDecoder.decode ((String) request.getParameter ("id"), "UTF-8")) ==> Ã©ssai
```

Anyone can help me to fix this charset problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getParameter()` returns decoded value, so you don't need to call `decode()`.

Configurtation of encoding used by `getParameter()` depends on your servlet container. For example, in Tomcat it can be configured using [`URIEncoding` attribute](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html).

Comment: Thank you, where can i configure this attribute? can i do this in my servlet? (because my application will be running on a distant server)

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your tip but that does not resolve my encoding problem, 
i've tried to type manually the accent in the adress bar and miracle that work!! 
so **i've solved my problem just removing the URLEncoder.encode() method** :)

Hope this can help someone, bye!!