# Retreiveing Encoded Value from URL

Tags: java, web-services, single-sign-on, url-parameters, ondemand

I have passes a encoded SSO token in URL...so the URL looks like

```
 http://127.0.0.1:7101/CRMOD_UCM-Sankalp-context-root/BrowseFile.jsp?token=%246%24zhxjx%2fpz6dVucl9cgG43ii2Tr4qVnNbeqJg8jCy6Jj7vRvXN4%3d%3b%246%24GlRGp%2fxfEM308NZGmY%2fhjHav2yjHSvbww1l0%2fCcCtcVjzl%2bCQFlQPdBRKO0t1XUmF0I6xLmfQ%2fnb7VgJeSYnvrAb9YUQQ3tvr%2fBZ%2bIRZiBAGU2%2fZg%3d
```

but when i retreive the value of variable and print it using 
out.println("SSO Token:"+request.getParameter("token"));
it prints

$6$zhxjx/pz6dVucl9cgG43ii2Tr4qVnNbeqJg8jCy6Jj7vRvXN4=;$6$GlRGp/xfEM308NZGmY/hjHav2yjHSvbww1l0/CcCtcVjzl+CQFlQPdBRKO0t1XUmF0I6xLmfQ/nb7VgJeSYnvrAb9YUQQ3tvr/BZ+IRZiBAGU2/Zg=

The correct token is which is present in the URL, WHY i am getting such a different value in my print...

Kindly help......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting encoded value if you want decode then use following code. By default system decode for us but in your case it is not decoded and you must explicitly decode value of request.getParameter("token").

```
String token = request.getParameter("token").toString();
// To decode url
String decodedtoken = URLDecoder.decode(token , "UTF-8");
System.out.println("Decoded token value "+ decodedtoken);

// To encode url 
String encodedtoken = URLEncoder.encode(token , "UTF-8"); 
System.out.println("Encoded token value "+ encodedtoken);
```

Answer (score 3):

`request.getParameter("token")` decodes the parameter value, so the value that gets printed is the decoded version of the parameter value in the URL.

See [Java EE, accent in url, request.getParameter wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741989/java-ee-accent-in-url-request-getparameter-wrong-value) for more information.

Comment: Then this is a big security threat as neone with the URL can simply use to deocode the token,Can you please tell me how can i avoid this

Answer (score 2):

In the URL, the token is [URL encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). This is necessary because some characters have special meanings in an URL.

By URL encoding the value, those special characters are replaced by `%nn` codes where `nn` is the character code of the special character.

Java automatically decodes it for you, so that you get the actual value when you call `request.getParameter("token")` instead of the URL-encoded value.

Comment: In fact %nn represents a byte, and it depends on web server configuration, which byte-char-mapping uses. Tomcat by example used ISO-8859-1 for Tomcat, but I don't know if it changed. So you have to be careful when you encode that value and use the same encoding.

Comment: Then this is a big security threat as neone with the URL can simply use to deocode the token,Can you please tell me how can i avoid this